# What does the phrase "binds stronger" mean?

Tags: computation-theory, ebnf

I know this might be a newbie question, but I'm trying to make sense of this sentence(from a paper on a meta language that uses  EBNF):

```
 Logical and (&) binds stronger than logical or (|).
```

Before that it says:

```
Conditions are: 
  condition ::= condition (`&´ | `|´ ) condition | `!´ condition | relation 
  relation ::= expression ( `=´ | `#´ | `<´ | `<=´ | `>´ | `>=´ ) expression
```

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This refers to [precedence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations). In other words, if you have `A & B | C`, you really have `(A & B) | C`. Operations with higher precedence/that bind stronger are evaluated first.