# Where clause skips condition

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I'm currently working on a project to make a hotel website and currently I'm working on the overview for reservations.

The query that I now have skips a critical step and it does not work does anyone have a solution for this

I have tried to chage the brackets and search on google but found nothing

SQL

```
select * 
  from reservations 
 where room_id = 1 
   and (CURRENT_DATE > reservation_start AND CURRENT_DATE < reservation_end) 
    or (CURRENT_DATE > reservation_start - 7);
```

Currently it gets al the rooms and not the room that has been given.

Comment: Show your table columns(with their datatypes) with 5-10 rows at least

Comment: can you remove last `or` condition and check it gives data or not for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put brackets around the conditions with CURRENT_DATE because `and` binds stronger than `or`:

```
select * from reservations 
where room_id = 1 
and ((CURRENT_DATE > reservations.reservation_start AND CURRENT_DATE < reservations.reservation_end) 
  or (CURRENT_DATE > reservations.reservation_start - 7)
);
```

Comment: [What does the phrase “binds stronger” mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16876455/what-does-the-phrase-binds-stronger-mean) to translate the meaning of *"and binds stronger than or:"* as it means [Operator precedence](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/operator-precedence.html)

Answer (score 0):

You have missed parentheses here. And the purpose of the query has changed.

```
select * from reservations 
  where room_id = 1 
    and ((CURRENT_DATE > reservations.reservation_start AND
          CURRENT_DATE < reservations.reservation_end) or 
          (CURRENT_DATE > reservations.reservation_start - 7));
```